# When is $Z(G/K)$ not $Z(G)/K$?

Tags: group-theory

I was just looking for some examples for groups $G$ and $K \unlhd G$ such that the centre of the quotient group $G/K$ is 'not just' $Z(G)/K$.

Comment: What does $Z(G)/K$ mean if $K$ is not a subgroup of $Z(G)$? Do you mean $Z(G)K/K$? Take $G$ to be the free group on more than one generator and $K=[G,G]$. (Thus, $G/K$ is the free abelian group on the generators but $Z(G)$ is trivial, so $Z(G/K)$ is all of $G/K$ but $Z(G)K/K$ is the trivial subgroup of $G/K$.)

Comment: Z(G)/K has a 'meaning'  in G/K. I don't know anything about free groups but I'll look into it.

Comment: Has a meaning? What?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

$$Z(S_3/A_3)\cong C_2=\text{ the cyclic group of ordet two , yet}\;\;Z(S_3)=\{(1)\}$$

and thus $\;Z(S_3)/A_3\;$ isn't even defined.